# uniform continuity

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

Let $F(s,y)$ be uniformly continuous in $[a,b] \times B$, where $B \subset R^n$ is a closed subset. Assume $x_k \rightarrow x$ in $C[a,b]$ with $x_k(t) \in B$ and prove

$$\int_a^b F(s,x_k(s)) ds \rightarrow \int_a^b F(s,x(s)) ds$$

To start the proof we estimate: $$\left| \int_a^b F(s,x_k(s)) - \int_a^b F(s,x(s)) \right| \leq |b-a| \sup_{[a,b]}{|F(s,x_k(s))-F(s,x(s))|}$$
The rest should follow from the uniform continuity of $F$ but can't figure out how exactly. Thank you!

P.S. I am confused because the two arguments of $F$ depend on $s$.

Comment: It might help to notice that $|(s,x_k(s)) - (s,x(s))| = |x_k(s) - x(s)|$, so the "second" $s$ doesn't actually matter.

Answer (score 1):

$$\left| \int_a^b F(s,x_k(s)) - \int_a^b F(s,x(s)) \right| \le\int_a^b\left|F(s,x_k(s))-F(s,x(s))\right|\,dx$$

As, $F$ is uniformly continuous so, $\left|F(s,x_k(s))-F(s,x(s))\right|<\epsilon/(b-a)$ , whenever $|x_k(s)-x(s)|<\delta$.

Can you continue ?